# Is there a quick way to arrive to this partial fraction decomposition?

Tags: calculus, analysis, partial-fractions

I'm reading a book where the author claims without showing the work that after we go through with the algebra of partial fractions we arrive to the formula (note $|z|<1$):
$$\frac{1}{(1-z)(1-z^2)(1-z^3)} = \frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{(1-z)^3}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{(1-z^2)}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{(1-z^3)}$$

Naturally, I'm trying to reproduce the result, but I'm taking a very naive approach, namely I've expressed the LHS as a product of irreducible factors over $\mathbb{R}$ and I am trying to determine the coefficients:
$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^3}\frac{1}{(1+z)}\frac{1}{(z^2+z+1)} = \frac{A}{(1-z)}+\frac{B}{(1-z)^2}+\frac{C}{(1-z)^3}+\frac{D}{(1+z)}+\frac{Ex+F}{(z^2+z+1)}$$

This seems to have some drawbacks though, because on top of being long winded, once I do obtain all the coefficients I will have to recombine some of the terms to arrive at the author's answer. My question is then: is there some sort of trick which we can use here which I am not aware of, or do we have to suffer through the algebra patiently?

Comment: There are some computational shortcuts (i.e. clear the denominators, then substitute in cleverly chosen values for $z$ in order to simplify the computations), but in general, you are going to have to do some computation.  But computation is good for the soul.

Comment: I guess residual theorem is the key..., they're all first order poles it should be really easy to compute in that way.

Comment: All first order poles except for $z = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all observe that

$$f(z) = \frac{-1}{(z-1)(z^2 - 1)(z^3 - 1)} = \frac{-1}{(z-1)^3(z+1)(z+1/2-i\sqrt{3}/2)(z+1/2+i\sqrt{3}/2)}$$

Remembering now the cauchy integral formula

$$
g^{(n)}(z_0) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \oint_{\gamma} \frac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz
$$

If, for example, you consider

$$
g(z) = \frac{-1}{(z-1)^3(z+1/2-i\sqrt{3}/2)(z+1/2+i\sqrt{3}/2)}
$$

we have

$$
g(-1) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\gamma} \frac{g(z)}{z+1}dz = \frac{-1}{(-8)(-1/2-i\sqrt{3}/2)(-1/2+i\sqrt{3}/2)}
$$

which is the coefficient of $A/(z+1)$, you can iterate through all the poles to obtain all the other coefficients, the only "tricky" one is the pole "z=1", which is a third order pole, so you it would a the calculation of a second derivative.

Comment: Of course you have to assume $\gamma$ goes around a single pole, not all of them together.

Comment: I quite like this approach although my background in complex analysis is not sufficient to fully understand the answer. I think this is probably as good as it gets.

Comment: What's your background?

Comment: Two courses in Real Analysis but no complex analysis (will come next semester, although I like to read the textbooks casually sometimes). One abstract algebra and one linear algebra course, but these aren’t very relevant to the question :)

Comment: Actually they're... If there's something you're missing I might be able to elaborate

Comment: There's anyway an algorithm whose theoretical bases are essentially given by the example above. It doesn't require to be wheel of science in general. The algorithm is usually explained in engineering classes.

Comment: I've been studying some complex analysis since the end of term and this makes perfect sense now, thank you!

Comment: Glad to be helpful! you just made my day =D.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of a shortcut (if you already know the coefficients).

Multiply the whole thing by $(1-z)(1-z^2)(1-z^3)$, to get 
\begin{align}
& \frac{1}{6}\frac{(1-z)(1-z^2)(1-z^3)}{(1-z)^3}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{(1-z)(1-z^2)(1-z^3)}{(1-z)^2}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{(1-z)(1-z^2)(1-z^3)}{(1-z^2)}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{(1-z)(1-z^2)(1-z^3)}{(1-z^3)}\\ \ \\
&= \frac{(1+z)(1+z+z^2)}{6}+\frac{(1+z)(1-z^3)}{4}+\frac{(1-z)(1-z^3)}{4}+\frac{(1-z)(1-z^2)}{3}\\ \ \\
&= \frac{2(1+z)(1+z+z^2)+3(1+z)(1-z^3)+3(1-z)(1-z^3)+4(1-z)(1-z^2)}{12}\\ \ \\
&=\frac{2(1+z)(1+z+z^2)+6(1-z^3)+4(1-z)(1-z^2)}{12}\\ \ \\
&=\frac{2z^3+4z^2+4z+2+6-6z^3+4-4z-4z^2+4z^3}{12}\\ \ \\
&=\frac{12}{12}=1.
\end{align}

Comment: This is a bit of backwards check though isn't it